# How to use wild card inside of fs.existsSync or statSync or readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, glob, fs

My spec below clicks on a download button and then verifies the download. 
The only problem in the program is that you need to know the name of the file in advance.

Rather I want it to look for a wild card in the directory like `*.mp4`
I have read up on `glob` but not sure how to implement it.

Can someone show me how to integrate it or another way, into code below? -

```
element(by.css('.download-recording .pgi-button-wrapper')).click();

browser.driver.wait(function() {

    return fs.existsSync('/home/user,/Downloads/Recordings/ProtractorMeeting-2019-01-24T21_56_24.000Z.mp4')}, 8000).then(function() {

        console.log("File Downloaded");
        console.log(fs.statSync('/home/user/Downloads/Recordings/ProtractorMeeting-2019-01-24T21_56_24.000Z.mp4').size);
        console.log(fs.readFileSync('/home/user/Downloads/Recordings/ProtractorMeeting-2019-01-24T21_56_24.000Z.mp4').length);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read whole directory with

fs.readdirSync

and then just filter received array of results, and generate abs path:

```
let fs = require('fs')
let folderfiles = fs.readdirSync('./')
console.log(folderfiles)
let mp4filePaths = folderfiles
    .filter(file=> file.endsWith('.mp4'))
    .map(file=> path.resolve(__dirname, file))
console.log(mp4filePaths)
```

Comment: Thank you @Xotabu4 , two questions, 1. I am using existsSync bc it waits for the file to be downloaded, how do I get readdirSync to first wait for the file to be downloaded? 2. How come you are looking in the root directory? (./) instead of looking into /Recordings directly?

Comment: @snikt you can try something like this:
browser.wait(function() {
  let folderfiles = fs.readdirSync("./");
  return folderfiles.some(file => file.endsWith(".mp4"));
}, 10000);

Comment: @snikt you can pass any folder path that you want, it is just example

Comment: Many thanks. Btw, what is purpose of calling `.map` ?